# driver.get(URL) not navigating to the specified URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

The webdriver is opening the browser but not navigating to the specified URL, and is returning the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/91800/PycharmProjects/Automation/automation.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
  File "C:\Users\91800\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\91800\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\91800\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: You need to provide path of the `chrome Driver` NOT path of the `chrome Browser `

Answer (score 0):

so first check whether your chrome version is the same as your web driver version..otherwise, there might be an issue executing the code
#to check the chrome version:
go to help in google chrome then to about google chrome and you will find a version there
#install the specific version of web driver from URL("https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads")
and...
it should be fine !!!